# View Reporting Services Reports as a Different AD User

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, active-directory, credentials, kiosk

I have some "kiosks" that run under machine specific AD accounts that I would like to deploy reports on.  For security reasons I need to verify individual user credentials before allowing access to the reports.  Is there a way to do this with reporting services?We are running Reporting Services 2005, but will be upgrading fairly soon.

Comment: How are individual users authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a custom security extension:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152899(SQL.90).aspx